# FindExecutable truncates file name in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

`FindExecutable` returns in the result buffer a truncated filename. Is it due to the fact that the filename is more than 8 chars?

Code:

```
strPath = "test12345.exe";
CString strDiraa = "c:\\test\\test";

TCHAR szExe[1024];
::FindExecutable(
    strFile,                                    // pointer to filename
    strDir.IsEmpty() ? 0 : LPCTSTR(strDir),     // pointer to default directory
    szExe                                       // result-buffer
    );
```

`szExe` is `c:\test\test\TEST12~1.EXE` but it should be `c:\test\test\TEST12345.EXE`.

Is there a way to have the right name?

Comment: That's the legacy *8.3* (short) format name, what version of windows are you using? Also why are you using FindExecutable on an EXE?

Comment: [LPCTSTR lpFile - This file should be a document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776419%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: You also have a big mish-mash of variable names (`strPath` vs `strFile`, `strDiraa` vs `strDir`).

Comment: That probably is the right name. Why do you think the name is wrong? What do you see in the registry for the association?

Comment: FindExecutable() isn't intended for use on `.exe` files, so it isn't surprising that you get a strange result.  You might want SearchPath() instead.

Comment: @SNC It would help if you replaced the fake code here with an actual [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `FindExecutable` gives you a "short" path name: it's a path name where all folder and file names are trucated to 8 characters (plus extension), using that funky DOS syntax (the `~1` thing).

Read more about path names here: [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Long story short, you have to use [GetFullPathName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364963%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the "DOSified" path name to get the complete file path:

```
TCHAR szExe[1024];
::FindExecutable(
    strFile,                                    // pointer to filename
    strDir.IsEmpty() ? 0 : LPCTSTR(strDir),     // pointer to default directory
    szExe                                       // result-buffer
    );

TCHAR fullPathName[1024];
GetFullPathName(szExe, sizeof(fullPathName), fullPathName, 0);
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this is right. Why would FindExecutable go looking for the short name. There might not even be one. More likely is that the file type was registered with short name of executable.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes that's correct, this has nothing to do with `FindExecutable`. I'll edit.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Actually, it seems OP is calling `FindExecutable` on an executable file, to get the full path name, so no reading of the registry here (?)

Comment: We don't know what is in strFile

Comment: `sizeof()` is not the way to specify the buffer length.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I don't know why, but it does.  If you feed it the name of an executable file, rather than the name of a document, it returns the short name.  If the file only has a long name, the call fails with a file not found error.  From the oddball signature and error handling, I'm guessing FindExecutable comes to us from Win16 days, so this behaviour is probably for backwards compatibility.

Comment: @Harry It's a little galling that we have to guess what the asker's code really is though.